# Odd runtime error in VBA: -2147352567

Tags: vba, ms-access

Morning,

I encountered this odd runtime error when I tried to perform an update to a field:

[image]

This occurred when the VBA code attempted to set a field (which is a normal textbox and doesn't have a date format set) to a text value from a table. It should set that textbox to "somename" to signify who made the change.
The second sentence seems wrong to me as the value returned is a string.

The VBA code that returns the error is actually a `BeforeUpdate` routine - could this be why?

```
Private Sub Stat_Code_BeforeUpdate(Cancel As Integer)
```

where `Stat_Code` is a combo-box on the same subform.

I looked about but couldn't find any solution that would explain this. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that the source table that the form was set up to write to was incorrect. The `Stat_Modify_User` field I described above was setup in a table whose value was set to `Date/Time` when it should have been `Text`

Note - this wasn't my error :) I was given this backend.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can't update a field in the BeforeUpdate event handler. [MSDN says](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa211264%28v=office.11%29.aspx):

> A run-time error will occur if you attempt to modify the data contained in the control that fired the BeforeUpdate event in the event's procedure.

`BeforeUpdate` usually is used to validate data. Maybe you can use `AfterUpdate` event instead?

Comment: Thanks for the reply 0xA3 - as is usually the way of things i found what was causing the error. See my post.